# Accessing child instance in Rabl using a custom foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I have a table called "decision" and each decision has more dependencies in the table "dependence". The table "dependence" is linked to the table "decision" by two foreign keys, called "decision_1_id" and "decision_2_id". When I am trying to print a decision I would want to print its dependencies using one of these two fields.
With this code:

```
object @decision
child :dependences do
   attributes :id, :decision_id_1, :decision_id_2, :relationship
end
```

Rabl will try to find "decision_id" field which does not exist. Do you know any solution for specifying the foreign key?

**UPDATE**

My models are the next ones:

```
class Dependence < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :decision_1, :class_name => 'Decision', :foreign_key => 'decision_1_id'
    belongs_to :decision_2, :class_name => 'Decision', :foreign_key => 'decision_2_id'
end

class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dependences
end
```

**UPDATE 2**
An example of output could be this one:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"First decision",
        "dependences": [
            {
                "id":1,
                "decision_1_id": 1,
                "decision_2_id": 2,
                "relationship": "depends on"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "decision_1_id": 1,
                "decision_2_id": 3,
                "relationship": "alternative for"
            }
        ]
    },
    .... // decision 2 + decision 3
]
```

Which meaning could be this one: Decision with id 1 depends on decision with id 2 and is alternative for decision with id 3.

Comment: please post your Models and their associations.  in your question, that will help alot.

Comment: I've just updated my post with adding the models from my project.

Comment: thanks,  so there are a few ways to do this, but its also important to know how you want the output to look like.  for example do you expect an array of objects (decision_1, decision_2) to be under the node  `decisions` , or are you flexible with how the output is structured?

Comment: I would want to have an array of 'decisions', each decision having an array of 'dependences' ('dependence' being the child of 'decision'). But please give me any reference or advice you think could help me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Firstly your association ` has_many :dependences` presumes that the child record(s) `dependence` has a field called `decision_id`.  you can quickly verify this by going to the console and trying
`Decision.first.dependences`. You'll trigger the same error. Since you have custom foreign keys for that model you need to designate them also in your Decision model. Basically `has_many :dependences` will not work as you have it defined.

Comment: So... Does an instance of Dependence, have two unique Decision parents? Can one exist and not the Other?  And can both actually be the same parent?

Comment: would you also expect this record to also show in your example above? `{
                "id": 99,
                "decision_1_id": 3,
                "decision_2_id": 1,
                "relationship": "alternative for"
            }`